# From where can i start magento extension development

Tags: magento

i am familiar with magento and also wrote some widget for magento as well , now i want to create some magento extension, Can you please help me out from where can i start the magento extension programming . Please advice me good tutorial and books

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The best resource I found is Alan Storm's (our fellow stacker) series of blog posts which he calls [Magento for PHP MVC Developers](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento). He explains all the issues relating to magento development in much detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll also find this extension a great start: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Daniel+Nitz/extension/1108/modulecreator.  You can trawl through the code it creates to get a really good idea of the key pieces of the puzzle.

Also, review the Magento sequence diagram to understand important steps in the flow: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/_detail/general/doc/page-request-flow.png?id=doc:magento-architecture&cache=cache

Answer (score 0):

Magento-Debug to navigate Magento's modules and layouts: https://github.com/madalinoprea/magneto-debug